# How can I block my code until a callback is finished in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm writing a web scraper, which looks like

```
function get_links(url){
    var links = new Array();
    get_page(url,function(page){
        links = parse_links(page);
    });
    return links;
}

while(true){
    var a = queue.pop_front();
    queue.push.apply(queue, get_links(a));
}
```

(the actual code contains other unrelated details, so I simplify it)

The problem is that, sometimes `return` is executed before the callback function, when `links` is still empty.

Comment: ... It *always* will be. You're going to need to wrap your head around async programming; you can't blindly "return values" from async functions. Use promises, use callbacks, use something that's async-oriented instead of pretending async isn't how all this stuff works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vqyncLr3/1/